# Printing elements under second diagonal in 2d Matrix in C

Tags: c, loops, matrix, multidimensional-array

Hello I have a code that shows the elements under the main diagonal of 2d matrix and I need to also show the elements under the second diagonal. any ideas what to manipulate in the loop.

```
// loop to show the elements under the main diagonal
void element_under_diag(int number, int arr[number][number])
{
   int i, j;

   printf("\nUnder the main diagonal:\n");
      for(i=0;i<number;i++){
         for(j=0;j<number;j++){
            if(i>j)
               printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
         }
      }
   printf("\n");

}
```

`number` is taken from the user in the main function and it's the number of row and columns in the matrix.

this loop result into an output like this:

```
The entered matrix is:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
Under the main diagonal:
4 7 8
```

Now I need the output to be something like this:

```
The entered matrix is:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
Under the secondary diagonal:
6 8 9
```

Comment: What are the indices of the off diagonal? Can you see a pattern there? Turn the pattern into an inequality.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

If an array is defined with N * N elements then the condition in the if statement can look like

```
if ( N - i - 1  < j ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
```

Answer (score 1):

condition is useless due it can be done strait through the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    int arr[3][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    element_under_diag(3,arr);
    element_under_secondary_diag(3,arr);
}

void element_under_diag(int number, int arr[number][number])
{
   printf("\nUnder the main diagonal:\n");
      for(int i=1;i<number;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
         }
      }
   printf("\n");
}

void element_under_secondary_diag(int number, int arr[number][number])
{
   printf("\nUnder the secondary diagonal:\n");
      for(int i=1;i<number;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            printf("%d ",arr[number-j-1][i]);
         }
      }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, replace in your program:

```
if(i>j)   // above the diagonal
```

with

```
if( (i+j) >= N )   // below the diagonal
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it this way:

```
// loop to show the elements under the main diagonal
void element_under_diag(int number, int arr[number][number])
{
   int i, j;
   printf("\nUnder the secondary diagonal:\n");
      for(i=1;i<number;i++){
         j = number - i; //Every time the row number goes up one, the starting column goes down one. 
           for(;j<number;j++){
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
         }

      }
   printf("\n");
}
```